# Filename encoding in Apache Commons Net FTPClient

Tags: java, utf-8, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have to upload a file to an FTP server. The filename contains special letters, say `äöü`. On the FTP server, I need the filename to be UTF-8 encoded.

My code is like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

...

boolean retval = client.storeFile(fileName, inputStream);
```

The problem is that after `storeFile`, the name of the file saved on the FTP server is ISO-8859-1 encoded rather than UTF-8.

How can I tell `FTPClient` to UTF-8 encode the file names?

Comment: I'd say you are looking in the wrong place, this is probably a configuration in the FTP server...

Comment: Not necessarily. The original FTP protocol spec did not support Unicode at all.  In order to use UTF-8 over an FTP connection, both parties have to agree to its use first.  The server has to report in the `FEAT` command that it even supports UTF-8 (see RFC 2640, though not all servers support that spec).  Some servers require clients to send non-standard `OPTS UTF8 ON` or `OPTS UTF-8 NLST` commands to activate UTF-8.  So that is the $1M question - what does `FTPClient` support, and what does the server support?  I would use a packet sniffer, like WareShark, to watch the FTP traffic and see.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have not tested it, but you can try [this](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#setControlEncoding%28java.lang.String%29):

```
client.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Yes, setControlEncoding is right. It is important, however, to call setControlEncoding before connect, otherwise it does not work. I actually think this is a piece of unfortunate design of the library, see also http://yaseb.wordpress.com/2012/03/07/apache-commons-unfortunate-design-of-ftpclient/

Comment: Also note that if your server is a Windows IIS FTP server, the fact that `UTF8` is allowed at the server will not mean that it will be used in connections unless, after connecting, you additionally issue an `OPTS UTF8 ON` command: `client.sendCommand("OPTS UTF8 ON");`

Answer (score 7):

Since Apache Commons NET 3.0 one can use `ftpClient.setAutodetectUTF8( true );` to enable autodetection of UTF-8 support on the FTP server. Like `setControlEncoding` it must be called before connection.

See the corresponding [javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setAutodetectUTF8(boolean)).